# $\lim_{y \rightarrow x} f(y) = f(x)$ for all x

Tags: limits, continuity

Does $\lim \limits_{y \rightarrow x} f(y) = f(x) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ imply $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R} (f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$? The conclusion of $f(x)$ is continuous seems plausible to me, but math is full of surprises. Is this conclusion true?

Comment: What is the definition of continuity at $x$?

Comment: Surely it implies that $f(y)$ exists for any value $x$, and so is continuous in the real domain?

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \wedge x \in D s.t. |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$

Comment: @Rob: Have you shown that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $f$ is defined at $a$, the limit as $x\to a$ of $f(x)$ exists, and the value of the limit is equal to the value of the function at $a$? If so, then... if not, convince yourself this is actually the case.